# How to Optimise a given problem time complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a question which says

Given an input

```
ababacad
```

The output should be all the `a`'s should come first together rest characters should follow their sequence as they were originally. i.e.

```
aaaabbcd
```

I solved it like below code

```
String temp="", first="" ;

for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
  if(str.charAt(i)!='a')
    temp=temp+str.charAt(i);
  else
    first=first+str.charAt(i);
} 

System.out.print(first+temp);
```

The output matches but it says it is still not optimised. I guess its already order of N complexity. Can it be optimised further.

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` instead of `+` on strings

Comment: Does your solution also work for input `ababadac`?

Comment: Is it for string immutabilty or optimization?

Comment: yes..it has to do with both. Because strings are immutable, when you concatenate them together, you create a new string and copy the characters from each of the other strings into the new string. This overhead increases the amount of time your algorithm takes to run. Using `StringBuilder` instead will optimize your solution.

Comment: You clearly can't get a better asymptotic lower bound than linear simply because you must look at all the array elements to verify they're in an acceptable order. It might be possible to get better constant multipliers than your method yields, if that's what you're after.

Comment: ohkay... actually I am an beginner - intermediate to programming so just thought of creating new strings would mainly create memory overhead rather than its time consumption

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja is it a sorting problem? Does your solution works for ababadacabb?

Comment: To elaborate on @Code-Apprentice comments, a good resource for learning about the StringBuilder class is available at [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: An alternative to StringBuilder is to arrange that the input not be an immutable String but possible a character array or mutable string class. Then, you can produce a highly efficient in place algorithm to perform this task.

Comment: You could count how many times 'a' occurs, initialize a char array and fill it with 'a's first and then fill the remaining part of array with remaining letters. Then convert char[] to String. Still O(n) but you can reduce one String's space as in you have first, temp.

Comment: @SomeDude This is same as what i did in else part counting a's too require scanning of whole string. Furthermore I even thought of just having the remaining characters other than a and then manually adding a string of a's whose length would be original strings length - obtained strings length of remaining characters that too requires O(n) so not much improvement. I am expecting somewhat to log(n) the complexity can be reached but I am not sure

Comment: The + makes it O(n^2). So, use a char array, swap values and return a new string from this char array.

Comment: Why don't you convert the string to char array, put an `Arrays.sort` on it and convert it back to String. Won't take more then nlog(n)

Answer (score 1):

Optimization here can mean string operations as well as the number of iterations. So, just to be on the safe side, you can implement it using arrays. The time complexity will be O(n) which is the minimum for this problem as you have to check every position for the presence of char 'a'.

```
String input = "ababacad";

char[] array = input.toCharArray();
char[] modified = new char[array.length];

int a = 0; // index for a
int b = array.length - 1; // index for not a

for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (array[i] != 'a')
        modified[b--] = array[i];
    else
        modified[a++] = array[i];
}

String output = new String(modified);
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: You can also do it in-place, by reversing the loop, but the overall time complexity would be the same, while in terms of memory it would be constant.